# Closing messagebox from modal dialog closes the dialog

Tags: wpf, xaml, dialog, modal-dialog, messagebox

I have a custom modal dialog from which I want to invoke a Messagebox on error. 
However on closing the messagebox, the dialog also closes.

Is there a way to keep the dialog open and just close the messagebox?

Comment: Post some code.. which you tried

Comment: Can somebody answer to this question? I have a similar issue. You call ShowDialog on some window, then on that window you show MessageBox and when the MessageBox is closed, the code after the ShowDialog call continues (which it should not).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Built in MessageBox Dialog Closing custom Form.ShowDialog()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916021/built-in-messagebox-dialog-closing-custom-form-showdialog)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the same issue as the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30916021/395685). I found a way to fix it and through it, probably proof that it is indeed a bug. My solution, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31905103/395685):

*A workaround on this is to add a handler for the FormClosing event of your form, so you can cancel it there.*

*It seems that the bug is somewhat detectable by checking `FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason`. This is normally "UserClosing" on normal close (even programmatically with calling `this.Close()`), but with this bug it's set to "None", a value I would assume is some kind of default that should normally never be used.*

```
private void form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.None)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
    // any other OnClose code you may wish to execute.
}
```

[EDIT]

**Sorry, the issue in the linked question was OP using `form.DialogResult` as temp variable for the result of a message box, and that caused the main form to close, so that is, in fact, *not* related. Use a temp variable for stuff like that, folks.**

**The most likely *real* cause of this is that the form's `AcceptButton` is set, and the actual accept button's code does validation. Even if the validation raises an error, `AcceptButton` will cause the form's `DialogResult` to be set to `OK`, which closes the form. To prevent this, either don't set the `AcceptButton` property and just set the `DialogResult` manually, or, on error, specifically clear the `DialogResult` by setting it to `DialogResult.None`.**