# Built in MessageBox Dialog Closing custom Form.ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, winforms

## Okay Problem As Follows:

I call up a custom form as follows:

```
SomeCustomForm _newForm = new SomeCustomForm();
_newForm.ShowDialog();
//**SOME OTHER CODE**
```

Now lets say we have some custom event (Mine is on a DataGridView DoubleClick):

```
private void dgvSomeGrid_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = dgvSomeGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(name, "Select this Merkmal?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        _someID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvMSomeGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        this.Close();
    }
    else if (DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

The dialog works fine in that the no and yes buttons behave as expected. My problem though is that irrespective of which button is clicked, the code jumps back to *//**SOMEOTHERCODE*. So in effect, the _newForm is just closed.

I obviously don't want this to happen as I am not done on the other form yet if the "No" button is clicked.

Any help?

## EDIT:

My apologies - for the sake of clarity. The grid mentioned above is on the _newForm. And the dialog is called from the _newForm.

This closes unexpectedly.

Comment: how about attaching event to your new form : _newForm.dgvSomeGrid_DoubleClick += dgvSomeGrid_DoubleClick; (not to the main one). The event is attached to your main form that's why it is launching event handler in it's context.

Comment: The Grid is on _newForm. So even though this grid is on newform will it still be bound to the "main" form? Not quite sure I understand.

Comment: Okay I understand what you meant now. Please see edit for clarity. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Move your //**SOME OTHER CODE** to a separate method and call it only if dialog result returns 'yes'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use `DialogResult` property of form for comparison. Set it only on successful close

```
private void dgvSomeGrid_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = dgvSomeGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    var result = MessageBox.Show(name, "Select this Merkmal?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        _someID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvMSomeGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Terrance00, on Yes click in MessageBox code sets _someID, set DialogResult and Close form. but on NO click this code does nothing and form should not be closed

Comment: Whooops My bad. This does work. Thanks alot. The forms get confused by the DialogResult object. Thanks bro. Upvoted and marked. Sorry for doubting you.

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in code type `static bool formCloseFlag = false;`

Let's shorten your event handler code a bit:

```
   private void dgvSomeGrid_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = dgvSomeGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(name, "Select this Merkmal?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            _someID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvMSomeGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            formCloseFlag = true;
        }
        return;
    }
```

then change your code like this :

```
SomeCustomForm _newForm = new SomeCustomForm();
_newForm.ShowDialog();
//**SOME OTHER CODE**
if(formCloseFlag) { _newForm.Close(); formCloseFlag = false; }
//**SOME OTHER CODE**
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround on this is to add a handler for the FormClosing event of your form, so you can cancel it there.

[edit]

After some experimenting, it seems that the bug is somewhat detectable by checking `FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason`. This is normally "UserClosing" on normal close (even programmatically with calling `this.Close()`), but with this bug it's set to "None", a value I would assume is some kind of default that should normally never be used.

```
private void form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.None)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
    // any other OnClose code you may wish to execute.
}
```